# Using Api keys with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to use api-keys for authorization and grouping users for accesing the api's in API Gateway. The requests will be sent from web-page using javascript calls.

1. Is there any way to encrypt the api-keys?
2. Lets say I am able to encrypt it, will it be beneficial at all? Because someone can still see the encrypted api-keys and use it, and it will still work, because anyhow i will be decrypting it somewhere.
3. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot protect your API keys for authorization when your API calls are initiated from the client (i.e., JavaScript). As you said, there will be no point of encrypting them as well. You'll need to have an authorization provider that can return the API key as part of the response.

API Gateway allows you to have custom authorizer for your API. See [Output from an Amazon API Gateway Custom Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-custom-authorizer-output.html).